# Can one prove that the logarithm tends to infinity in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that things are usually done the other way around but I wonder if one can use the divergence of harmonic series (which can be proven with a simple grouping argument) to prove that the (natural) logarithmn tends to infinity?

Comment: In fact this is possible : You can show $$\int_1^n \frac{1}{n}>\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{j}$$ for every positive integer $n$ by using a suitable staircase-function. The left side is just $\ln(n)$ and the right side is the harmonic sum minus $1$ which diverges. Therefore $\ln(n)$ must diverges and because of the fact that the ln-function strictly increases , $\ln(x)$ must tend to $\infty$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Absolutely.....